# how to use dict.get()'s default argument with complex data

Tags: python, dictionary

Here's a script for counting words that uses the default argument of the dict.get() method:

```
word_list = ['abc', 'abc', 'def']
word_data = {}

for word in word_list:
    word_data[word] = word_data.get(word, 0) + 1

print(word_data)
```

This works well for simple counting. But if I want to collect more data, say the index of the word entry in word_list, then I need to insert this extra data into both get()'s default argument and the trailing expression ("+ 1").

How can I do that?

Comment: Could you give a more realistic example about "more data"?  Because most people would just directly use a `collections.Counter` for the example you've shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna keep using `dict.get` method, then, you could do it in this way:

```
 for i, word in enumerate(word_list):
     elem = word_data.get(word, {'index':[], 'count':0})
     word_data.update({
         word: {
             'indexes': elem['indexes']+[i], 
             'count': elem['count']+1
         }
     })
```

Then, as a result, you would get:

```
{'abc': {'count': 2, 'indexes': [0, 1]}, 'def': {'count': 1, 'indexes': [2]}}
```

Although, in this particular case, maybe it would be more effective just to keep track of the indexes (since the number of occurrences for each word would be just the length of that list), right? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for word in sorted(set(word_list)):

    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(word_list) if x == word]
    counts = word_list.count(word)

    word_data[word] = {}
    word_data[word]['count'] = counts
    word_data[word]['indexes'] = indices
```

hope this helps mate!